# Pandas will not install, different error than other posts here

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I first tried installing pandas after installing the newest version of python 3.10.0 on my Mac, and read here that pandas is not yet supported on the newest version, so I installed python 3.9.10 instead, and I am getting the same exact error within both versions:

Python 3.9.10 (v3.9.10:f2f3f53782, Jan 13 2022, 16:55:46)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
'''

> > > pip3 install pandas
> > > SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> > > pip install pandas
> > > SyntaxError: invalid syntax

It may also be important to note that the "i" in install gets highlighted in red every time.
'''

Comment: pip is a system command, not Python function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to delete questions, however I figured it out on my own

Comment: Please update your post with the solution to let everyone know!

Answer (score 0):

right click on your windows powershell and open with ,(Run as Administrator).
and type (pip install pandas).